# What time are Bloomberg Open Symbology Files updated daily?

Tags: data, bloomberg

Does anyone know what time the [Bloomberg Open Symbology](http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/) precanned files are updated every day? I am planning on upating my view of them at 9 AM EST every morning. Furthermore, will the files for equities have any IPOs from the day listed?

Comment: I spent about an hour trying to find the answer to your question, as I am really curious about Bloomberg Open Symbology. Best I could find was that they ARE updated once daily, but no specifics.

Comment: What is the concern?  I pay for Bloomberg Back office files and usually ipos are listed well in advance

Answer (score 2):

Bloomberg Open Symbology precanned files are updated twice daily.  8am and 2pm est

Comment: Do you have a source for that?